# JSON Website response into Python dictionary

Tags: python, json

I'm trying to load a JSON response from a website into a Python (2.7) dictionary, but am getting stuck iterating through more than the outer JSON object.

E.g. the website response looks like:

```
{
  "movies": [
    {
      "movieTitle": "True Lies",
      "Cert": "15",
      "Released": "1987",
    },
     {
      "movieTitle": "Scary Movie",
      "Cert": "18",
      "Released": "1997",
    },
```

My Python is as follows, and when printing 'json_object' I see all of the data, but how can I get the JSON array held within 'json_object' into a Python list / dictionary?

```
response = requests.get('https://api.foo.com/movies/all', headers=headers)
json_object = json.loads(response.text)
print json_object
```

Comment: The question is unclear. `json_object` is a dict; `json_object["movies"]` is a list. Where exactly are you having problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to iterate over each movie, Use:

```
json_object = json.loads(response.text)
for movie in json_object['movies']:
    print movie['movieTitle']
```

Comment: Perfect, this was the missing link in my logic. Many thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Try using `json.loads`. It shall convert your json into a python dictionary and you can access the elements now and manipulate them as you normall would in a python dict.

```
dict1 = json.loads(json_object)
```

For eg, to obtain the movie title:

```
title = dict1["movies"][0]["movietitle"]
```

Comment: How does this help? OP is already using `json.loads`, as shown in the code.

Comment: This is wrong too. dict1['movies'] is a list. This will throw an error